# Is it considered good practice to edit region based spellings?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, spelling

Recently I've noticed that some of my questions/answers on various communities have been edited for reasons such as "spelling mistakes".

They've included things such as changing "initialise" to "initialize" and other things in that nature.

As I am from Ireland and speak Irish English, which is more or less the same as British English, the words I am typing are correct.
Side note: even as I typed "initialize" in that earlier example - the z version is underlined in red to show an error.

Am I in the wrong here and should I be using American spellings for Stack Exchange communication or are those people just a bit narrow minded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not considered good practise.

By all means fix clear and obvious spelling and grammar mistakes, but leave these differences alone.

The only place where American spellings are enforced are in tags - but even there we can suggest the British spellings as synonyms.